# Is there a generalised parallelogram inequality in uniformly convex spaces

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

A version of generalized parallelogram inequality in Hilbert spaces  is $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\|\alpha_i x_i\|^2=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i\| x_i\|^2-\sum_{i\neq j}^{n}\alpha_i\alpha_j\| x_i-x_j\|^2$
$\alpha_i\in (0,1)$. Is there a generalization of this inequality to uniformly convex Banach spaces(especially $L_p$ spaces)

Comment: You mean equality and not inequality I think.

Comment: what kind of inequality do you expect? May be [this is what you are looking for](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarkson's_inequalities)

Comment: Clarksons Inequality is not an efficient generalization of this theorem to n linearly independent vectors. Of-course, equality holds only in a Hilbert space. So I expect some inequality. For $1<p<\infty$,  we have due to the convexity of the map $\phi (t)=t^p$ that $\|\sum_{k=1}^{n}\alpha_k x_k\|^p\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n}\alpha_k\|x_k\|^p$ provided that $\alpha_k\in (0,1)$ and $\sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k=1$

Comment: What you've written is wrong since $\sum_{i=1}^n ||\alpha_i x_i||^2$ vanishes from both LHS and RHS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parallelogram law in Hilbert spaces can be written as 
$$\mathbf E \left\| \sum_{j=1}^n \epsilon_j x_j \right\|^2
=\sum_{j=1}^n \| x_j\|^2 
\tag1 $$
where $\epsilon_j\in \{-1,1\}$ and $\mathbf E$ is the average over all $2^n$ choices of signs of $\epsilon_j$. (In probabilistic terms, $\mathbf E$ is expectation, and $\epsilon_j$ are independent Bernoulli variables.)

The natural counterparts of (1) in a Banach space $X$ are the type inequality
$$\mathbf E \left\| \sum_{j=1}^n \epsilon_j x_j \right\|^r
\le T \sum_{j=1}^n \| x_j\|^r 
\tag{T} $$
and the cotype inequality
$$\sum_{j=1}^n \| x_j\|^r\le C  \mathbf E \left\| \sum_{j=1}^n \epsilon_j x_j \right\|^r
\tag{C} $$
The constants $T$ and $C$ must be independent of the choices of vectors $x_j\in X$.

The following are true:

1. $L^p$ satisfies (T) with $r=\min(p,2)$, for  $1\le p<\infty$.
2. $L^p$ satisfies (C) with $r=\max(p,2)$, for  $1\le p<\infty$.
3. More generally, every uniformly convex space satisfies (T) with some $1<r\le 2$ and (C) with some $2\le r<\infty$.

Reference: *Asymptotic Theory of Finite Dimensional Normed Spaces* by Milman and Schechtman.